# How to disable filtering on one column and keep it for other columns in a jQuery Datatable?

Tags: jquery, filter, datatables

I am new to jQuery and I need to know if there's any way to disable filtering for one of the columns in my jQuery datatable? 
My datatable has 5 columns and I need to disable filtering for the last column.

Comment: I use the default bFilter for searching the datatable but I dont want the filter to search only in the last column.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

[Use the `bSearchable` flag](http://datatables.net/usage/columns#bSearchable). From the docs:

```
// Using aoColumnDefs
$(document).ready( function() {
  $('#example').dataTable( {
    "aoColumnDefs": [
      { "bSearchable": false, "aTargets": [ 0 ] }
    ] } );
} );


// Using aoColumns
$(document).ready( function() {
  $('#example').dataTable( {
    "aoColumns": [
      { "bSearchable": false },
      null,
      null,
      null,
      null
    ] } );
} );
```

Comment: In new version (1.10+) of dataTable you can use `"searchable": false` flag for column on table initialization.

Comment: What's the full syntax of searchable?

Answer (score 4):

Also you can do it like this:

```
    $('#ProductsTable').dataTable({
        "lengthMenu": [[20, 50, -1], [20, 50, "All"]],
        "pageLength": 20,
        "columnDefs": [
          { "orderable": false, "targets": [-1, 1] },
          { "searchable": false, "targets": [-1, 1] }
        ]
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 var mSortingString = [];
var disableSortingColumn = 4; 
mSortingString.push({ "bSortable": false, "aTargets": [disableSortingColumn] });



    $(document).ready(function () {
        var table = $('#table').dataTable({
            "paging": false,
            "ordering": true,
            "info": false,
            "aaSorting": [],
            "orderMulti": true,
            "aoColumnDefs": mSortingString

        });
     });
```

I spent ages trying to figure this out which should have been a simple task so for anyone still looking just add in the top 3 lines and reference which column you want to disable, mine being column 5.

Answer (score 2):

Here's how to disable global search filtering on multiple columns using [Datatable ColumnDef](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columnDefs).

```
var datatable = $('#datatable').DataTable({
    "deferRender": true,

    "columnDefs": [ 
        { targets: 0, searchable: true },
        { targets: [1,2], searchable: true },
        { targets: '_all', searchable: false }
    ]
});
```

This will enable search on column 0, 1 & 2 index wise and disable on rest of them all. The rules apply from top to bottom taking priority.

Answer (score 1):

This also works. Just change the number 4 to your desired column number:

```
    var table = $('#mytable').DataTable(
        {
            initComplete: function () {
                this.api().columns().every(function () {
                    var column = this;
                    if (column[0][0] == 4) {
                        console.log(column);
                        $(column.footer()).html('');
                    }
                });
            },
        }
    );
```